# INNER JOIN combining 2 columns

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have a regular table with employee info:
  ID int
  NAME varchar

Besides that I have a table with purchases. The employee id is listed here
again either in the column seller or contractor. It is possible that a employee
has not done any sales. It is also possible that no contractor or no seller is involved.

```
EMPLOYEES
ID  NAME
1   Bill
2   Cliff
3   Mary
4   Jon

PURCHASES
ID  SELLER  CONTRACTOR
1   1       2
2   1     
3   2       1
4   2       3
```

I want to get the list with the employee id and name and information if
this employee is listed in the seller and/or contractor columns. So basically
if this employee has done any sales.

```
ID  NAME    SALES
1   Bill    1
2   Cliff   1
3   Mary    1
4   Jon     0
```

What I get is double lines when employees are listed in multiple sales. I have tries numerous LEFT JOIN statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select e.*,
  exists (select 1 from purchases where e.id in (seller, contractor)) sales
from employees e
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8gFDjNuL6dNss6k6vk4GAW/0).
Or with a LEFT JOIN and aggregation:

```
select e.id, e.name, max(p.id) is not null sales
from employees e left join purchases p
on e.id in (p.seller, p.contractor)
group by e.id, e.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8gFDjNuL6dNss6k6vk4GAW/1).
Results:

```
| ID  | NAME  | sales |
| --- | ----- | ----- |
| 1   | Bill  | 1     |
| 2   | Cliff | 1     |
| 3   | Mary  | 1     |
| 4   | Jon   | 0     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT` based on column from "outer table":

```
SELECT e.ID, e.name, COUNT(p1.seller) AS cnt_seller, COUNT(p2.contractor) AS cnt_contractor
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN Purchases p1
  ON e.ID = p1.seller
LEFT JOIN Purchases p2
  ON e.ID = p2.contractor
GROUP BY e.ID, e.name
```